# Deploy Mesosphere Universe package like Marathon-lb via curl command

Tags: curl, mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

We can deploy the package with dcos commands like

```
dcos package install marathon-lb
```

but this requires dcos authentication with `dcos auth login` and since it requires to manually open the browser and paste the code , This is not feasible in automated script.

And with curl command I am able to deploy app like

```
curl -H "Authorization: token=token" -X POST http://azurehost/service/marathon/v2/apps -d @app.json -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

But how to deploy the universe package ?
I want to deploy `Marathon-lb via curl or script`. So where can I find official marathon.json i.e. application definition to deploy via curl command?

Comment: maybe put dcos behind a proxy  with logging capabilities and see what protocol it uses? if it uses encryption, use a proxy with mitm decryption capabilities, like Fiddler Proxy. if you do that, please post your results in the post (and censor the sensitive data ofc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Marathon-LB from universe package then accessed `http://azurehost.azure.com/marathon/v2/apps` where I got the correct marathon application definition of Marathon-lb. Now I am using the same definition through curl command and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Managing dcos universe packages (describe/list/install/uninstall/search etc) via http api is an ENTERPRISE FEATURE.
If you are using Enterprise DCOS Cluster, then you can use them as documented here :
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/deploying-services/package-api/